# How to make sure, when you groupby lists. You dont get the grouped by rows, with empty lists

Tags: python, pandas

My issue is the following

I have the following sample data.

| UserId | OriginLink |
| --- | --- |
| A | potato |
| B |  |
| A | apple |
| B |  |

When i run the following line of code.

```
prod.groupby(['UserId'])['OriginLink'].apply(lambda d : list(d)).reset_index()
```

I get the following result:

| UserId | OriginLink |
| --- | --- |
| A | [potato,apple] |
| B | [,,] |

How can i guarantee that it doesn return the empty list in the B row. I tried a few if statement, but it didnt work

Wanted result

| UserId | OriginLink |
| --- | --- |
| A | [potato,apple] |

Comment: Also worth noting: `lambda` is unnecessary when grouping as list, you can replace `.apply(lambda d : list(d))` with `.apply(list)` with the same result and save yourself some typing in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dropna if you want to drop anything that is null

```
prod.dropna(inplace = True)
prod.groupby(['UserId'])['OriginLink'].apply(lambda d : list(d)).reset_index()
```